# sprite image is not cropping in css

Tags: html, css, image, menu, sprite

so i'm trying to do a sprite image for the bottom links we have for our media and i'm not getting the image to crop properly, where is my mistake?

CSS

```
.footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    margin:5px;
    border:2px solid grey;
    width:200px;
    height:55px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
}

#twitter{
    background:url('http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg') no-repeat;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    display:block;
}

#twitter a:hover{
    background:url('http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg');
    background-position: 0 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
<a href="https://twitter.com/unified4unifat" id="twitter" class="imglink" >
<img src="http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg" alt="U4U's Twitter"
/>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: sry here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NV6zw/

Comment: maybe something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/NV6zw/5/

Comment: thanks david but can you figure out why i can't get the image that is supposed to lay next to the twitter one (the facebook one) to show? see this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/uZHUb/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work doing this (although you probably don't need the !important tag): http://jsfiddle.net/NV6zw/6/

```
<div class="footer">
<a href="https://twitter.com/unified4unifat" id="twitter" class="imglink" ></a>
```

```
.footer{

margin:5px;
border:2px solid grey;
width:200px;
height:55px;
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
}
#twitter{
    background:url('http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg') no-repeat;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    display:block;
}
#twitter:hover{
    background:url('http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg');
    background-position: -50px 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: For a minimal working example you can also remove much of the CSS here : The `background` from `#twitter:hover` as well as the entire `.footer` class aren't needed to do the sprite rollover.

Comment: hey   thanks a lot chad, looks like that did it. i am still in the learning stages of CSS and i have always been told to avoid the !important tag so i think i will.....but looks like your solution is working...guess i was not supposed to have the src="" in my html?

Comment: thanks lmjohns, yea i didn't post the rest of the html code but it is part of a larger document, thanks for the feedback though, i'm still a beginner so no doubt my code is bloated...can you explain though why the background:url property is not needed in the 2nd #twitter:hover?

Comment: hey well i have the twitter side working but not it is now showing the facebook icon next to it when i set that up, see fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/uZHUb/1/    this is frustrating!

Comment: hey well i found the problem, was as simple as putting "px" after the background-position values: here is the fiddle for anyone who minds:http://jsfiddle.net/uZHUb/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one of the twitter pics to show in the footer with the class you need to set .footer width to 50px instead of the full 200px of the image

Comment: hey...sorry i didn't clarify...i'm going to be just using the twitter on the far right of the gray box (probably with a float:left;) but and then next to that do the same thing with a facebook icon (as you can see in the sprite image i created).....

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    margin:5px;
    border:2px solid grey;
    height:55px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
   }

   #twitter{
     background:url('http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg') no-
     repeat;
     height:50px;
     width:50px;
     background-position: 0 0;
     display:block;
   }

   #twitter a:hover{
   background:url('http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg');
   background-position: 0 50px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/unified4unifat" id="twitter" class="imglink" >
    <!--<img src="http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg" alt="U4U's     
    Twitter"-->
    <!--/>-->
       <div style="background:  
         url('http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/resources/social.jpg');width: 
         50px;height:50px; background-repeat: no-repeat"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```